# FATAL ERROR: Call to undefined function wp_raise_memory_limit()

Tags: php, wordpress

Al querer entrar en el Admin de mi Wordpress, meto las claves y es imposible acceder al panel de admin. Y me sale este mensaje:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_raise_memory_limit() in /home/u876614381/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php on line 141**

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer dicho problema ocurre después de una actualización fallida de WordPress.

Según esta [respuesta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238043/admin-blank-page-with-working-front-end-after-updating-to-wordpress-4-6) del sitio de WordPress de StackExchange, podrías resolverlo haciendo una actualización manual:

1. Descargar la (última) versión deseada de WordPress.
2. Sobreescribir los archivos actuales, excepto `wp-config.php` y la carpeta `wp-content`.
3. Al ingresar al sitio web, va a solicitar una actualización de Base de Datos, la cual debes realizar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Shaz! Arreglado y a pleno rendimiento, Gracias de veras!

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil, puedes marcarla como aceptada.